# Makefile: problem getting ifstatement to work =(

Tags: c++, makefile

```
MAC_BOOST_PATH = -L/opt/local/lib
LINUX_BOOST_PATH = -L/usr/lib/
DEFAULT_PATH = -L/usr/local/lib
BOOST_PATH = $(DEFAULT_PATH)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
BOOST_PATH = MAC_BOOST_PATH
@echo Compiling for Mac OS X
@echo 
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
BOOST_PATH = LINUX_BOOST_PATH
@echo Compiling for Linux
@echo 
endif
```

The echo's aren't printing, and the BOOST_PATH isn't changing, I don't think... So... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here... =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put commands in a Makefile independent of targets. You need to introduce a target which displays the OS. Also, you're lacking '$()'. Use e.g.

```
UNAME=$(shell uname)
MAC_BOOST_PATH = -L/opt/local/lib
LINUX_BOOST_PATH = -L/usr/lib/
DEFAULT_PATH = -L/usr/local/lib
BOOST_PATH = $(DEFAULT_PATH)

ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
BOOST_PATH=$(MAC_BOOST_PATH)
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)
BOOST_PATH=$(LINUX_BOOST_PATH)
endif

all: showos

showos: 
  @echo compiling for $(UNAME)
```

Answer (score 3):

You’re not defining the `UNAME` variable anywhere. You probably want something like this:

```
UNAME = $(shell uname)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the @ signs to get the echos to appear

Comment: No need for that. The `@` merely suppresses the echoing of the command itself.

Answer (score 0):

As Erik points out, Make will not execute commands independent of targets. But it can evaluate functions without targets:

```
UNAME = whatever

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
BOOST_PATH = MAC_BOOST_PATH
$(info Compiling for Mac OS X)
$(info )  # note the space
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
BOOST_PATH = LINUX_BOOST_PATH
$(info Compiling for Linux)
$(info )
endif
```